# How to track user location in background, react native?

Tags: react-native, geolocation, location-services, google-location-services

I am using the react-native-geolocation-service package, and everything works like a charm. But now I am required to track a users location both in the foreground and in the background. I was wandering if the watchPosition method supports background location watching or is it just when in the app? and if it doesn't support it, what would be the alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used it in the past and it's not straightforward. I tried with the package you mentioned and a few others. I've settled up for the [react-native-background-geolocation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation).

You might encounter problems when switching from the background to the foreground (assuming you also need to track the location in the foreground). They can be fixed by adding a Listener.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It says it is 349$ a year. Is this the full cost or are there any additional costs? and does this work with ios and android? Thanks

Comment: this works with iOS and Android. 
Not sure about the costs as I/we never deployed the app: the Owner decided to increase the scope of the project and in the meanwhile I left the team.
We had minor success with this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation . Maybe you want to give it a try (despite having the same name they are not compatible)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So i have set-up the package in the app and i am having issues in the foreground. Unfortunately I am having issues when the app is running. While in the app, I am receiving a response with the location and it is being tracked as it should be, but i am getting updates every 16 seconds, which is way too frequent. I have applied the distanceFilter to 5000 but still every 16 seconds i get updates. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: @JunaidRazaq IIRC the Android and iOS "output" a location in different ways. I think the `distanceFilter` is something like "minimum distance travelled to give a new location". So only if you travelled 5000 meters the device would "output" a new position (but there's also other configs/conditions you can change to have a new position sooner or later).
Also if 16 seconds is way too frequent just dump the value, or keep storing the latest value and only process it when needed.